# Equilibrium for a game with mixed strategies on a compact ultrametric space

Tags: gn.general-topology, game-theory, nash-equilibrium

Let $(X,d)$ be a compact ultrametric space. Hartig and de Vink considered the following ultrametric on the set $P(X)$ of probability on $X$:
$$\hat d(\mu,\nu)=\inf\{r>0:\forall x\in X\;\;\mu(B_r(x))=\nu(B_r(x))\}.$$
One can consider games on $X$ with mixed strategies in $(P(X),\hat d)$.

**Problem.** *(Dis)prove the existence of an equilibrium for such a game.*

---

This problem was posed on 12 March 2022 by Mykhailo Zarichnyi on [page 116](http://www.math.lviv.ua/szkocka/viewpage.php?vol=3&page=116) of [Volume 3](http://www.math.lviv.ua/szkocka/viewbook.php?vol=3) of [Lviv Scottish Book](http://www.math.lviv.ua/szkocka/view.php).

**Prize:** A bottle of ``Tuca".

Comment: What is assumed about the payoff-functions? And what is the role of the ultra-metric $\hat{d}$ here?